# Hackerrank: Frequency Queries Question Getting Timeout Error, How to optimize the code further?

Tags: java

I am getting timeout error for my code which I wrote using hashmap functions in java 8.When I submitted my answer 5 test cases failed due to timeout error out of 14 test cases on hackerrank platform.

Below is the question

You are given  queries. Each query is of the form two integers described below:

1. x  : Insert x in your data structure.
2. y  : Delete one occurence of y from your data structure, if present.
3. z  : Check if any integer is present whose frequency is exactly z. If yes, print 1 else 0.

The queries are given in the form of a 2-D array of  where queries[i][0]  contains the operation, and queries[i][1] contains the data element.

How should I optimize this code further ?

```
static HashMap<Integer,Integer> buffer = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

          // Complete the freqQuery function below.
        static List<Integer> freqQuery(List<List<Integer>> queries) {



        List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<>();


        output = queries.stream().map(query -> {return performQuery(query);}).filter(v -> v!=-1).collect(Collectors.toList()); 
        //get the output array iterate over each query and perform operation


        return output;

        }

        private static Integer performQuery(List<Integer> query) {

            if(query.get(0) == 1){
                buffer.put(query.get(1), buffer.getOrDefault(query.get(1), 0) + 1);
            }
            else if(query.get(0) == 2){
                if(buffer.containsKey(query.get(1)) && buffer.get(query.get(1))>0 ){
                    buffer.put(query.get(1), buffer.get(query.get(1)) - 1);
                }
            }
            else{
                if(buffer.containsValue(query.get(1))){
                    return 1;
                }
                else{
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }



        public static void main(String[] args) {


            List<List<Integer>> queries =  Arrays.asList(
                                            Arrays.asList(1,5),
                                            Arrays.asList(1,6),
                                            Arrays.asList(3,2),
                                            Arrays.asList(1,10),
                                            Arrays.asList(1,10),
                                            Arrays.asList(1,6),
                                            Arrays.asList(2,5),
                                            Arrays.asList(3,2)
                                            );
          long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            System.out.println(freqQuery(queries));


            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
               //finding the time difference and converting it into seconds
                  float sec = (end - start) / 1000F;
                  System.out.println("FreqQuery function Took "+sec + " s");
    }
    }
```

Comment: What is the range of the inputs?

Comment: The queries range can be anything, N number of queries can be there

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is the `z` operation. Sepecifically, the method `containsValue` has linear time complexty, making the whole complexity of the algorithm in the order of `O(n*n)`. Here is a hint: add another hashmap on top of the one that you have which counts the occurences of occurences by value of the other map. In that way you can query directly this second one by the value (because it will be the key in this case).

Comment: Can you give directly give me the modified version of my code which includes your logic ? I am not understanding your logic.